# Meaningless ability to edit deleted chat messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, undelete

The following sequence of events recently transpired:

1. I thwacked the enter key in the middle of writing a chat message.
2. To avoid embarrassment, I immediately deleted said message.
3. I then was able to edit the deleted message, completing my half-finished thought.
4. However, it proved impossible to resurrect said deleted message *even though the edit was applied to the edit stack*.

It seems to me that the functionality to edit deleted messages should not be present given that deleted messages cannot be undeleted. All this does is leave the user confused after spending the time to edit the message which cannot be displayed.

If there exist some superpowers that allow mods or high-rep users to undelete messages, making this feature at least *somewhat* relevant for somebody, then it should still be blocked for us plebs.

Comment: Well, you can copy and paste the complete message, it's not lost.

Comment: Certainly, and that's in fact what I did. But that doesn't change the fact that this is a terrible bit of interface that confuses the user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Agreed, and [fixed now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250586/115866). Thanks.