# You can edit deleted messages in mobile chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, mobile-web

Similar to this question ([Meaningless ability to edit deleted chat messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234783/meaningless-ability-to-edit-deleted-chat-messages)) (which appears to have been fixed), but in *mobile* chat. I went into mobile chat, deleted my last message, then clicked 'edit last'. It brought up the deleted message and I was able to edit it. [Here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/messages/3116080/history)'s the post history:

[image]

And if that isn't a bug ... then fix the incorrect message, "**Last version before deletion**", above the last version *after* deletion...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yeah, that made no sense. Note that all other restrictions to editing still applied (in particular the 2-minute limit), so this wasn't a major problem -- just useless and potentially confusing.

Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: That was fast... I had experimented a bit, and did notice that the 2-min limit had still applied.